# Dynamic Dependent Dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a form that pulls some dropdown data from an existing db. I've been working on a second dropdown that references the first to get more specific information from a different DB, however it looks like my code is broken somewhere. The first dropdown is populated fine but when i choose a "Manager" the Site dropdown goes blank, I even lose the "Select Site" option.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    function getSite(val) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"get_site.php",
        data:'manager_id='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#site-list").html(data);
        }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

html/php

```
Manager<br/>
<select name="manager_id" onChange="getSite(this.value);">
<option value="">Select Manager</option>
<?php
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM _managers");
while ($row_unit = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_unit["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row_unit["company"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<br/><br/>
        Site<br/>
<select name="site_id" id="site-list">
<option value="">Select Site</option>
</select>
```

get_site.php

```
<?php
include('includes/connect-db.php');

if(!empty($_POST["manager_id"])) {
    $manager_id = $_POST["manager_id"];
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM _sites WHERE manager_id = $manager_id");
?>
    <option value="">Select Site</option>
<?php
    while ($row_site = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_site["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row_site["site_name"]; ?></option>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$("#site-list").append(data);`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Saurabh. I made the adjustment but still not getting my values from the "get_site.php" file. Although now the "Select Site" stays in the site dropdown.

Comment: It is because you are echoing inside while loop.first get all data into an array then echo that variable. I personally prefer echo using `json_encode`

Answer (score 0):

As per discussion in comment.

> I made the adjustment but still not getting my values from the
>   "get_site.php" file. Although now the "Select Site" stays in the site
>   dropdown.

Assuming you are getting proper data from MySQL server do some changes in `get_site.php` as below.

**get_site.php**

```
<?
include 'includes/connect-db.php';

if ((!empty($_POST["manager_id"])) && (isset($_POST["manager_id"])))
{
    $manager_id = $_POST["manager_id"];
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM _sites WHERE manager_id = '{$manager_id}'");
    $options = "<option value=''>Select Site</option>";
    while ($row_site = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
    {
        $options .= "<option value='{$row_site['id']}''>{$row_site['site_name']}</option>";
    }
    return $options; // I personally prefer to echo using json_encode and decode it in jQuery
}
?>
```

Above code should give you the data you want.
Hope this solves your issue.Do comment if you are having any difficulties.